# Why is there no built-in HashMapStreamSerializer in Hazelcast?

Tags: hazelcast

The Hazelcast documentation provides examples of how we can write our own LinkedListStreamSerializer and HashMapStreamSerializer and it says that support will be added for these in the future.

It looks as though the LinkedListStreamSerializer is in fact supported now, which is great, but not the HashMap one.

I'm wondering if there is any reason why not and should I be concerned about continuing to use the example one from the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine with the HashMapStreamSerializer.

It's now tricky to add a new serializer into Hazelcast due backward compatibility - as older clients wouldn't be able to deserialize blobs serialized with the new serializer.